# Can I use my raspberry Pi camera underwater?

Tags: camera, streaming

Hi i am new to using a raspberry pi and this will be my first project, i want to make a fish camera to put in my fishtanks to be able to watch them when i am away, will the camera be able to go underwater also can any of you link me to a project like this so i have some instructions on how to set it up? would it also be possible to stream to a phone/create an app?

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the camera underwater without significant effort to protect and waterproof the electronics, but you could use this [mount](https://thepihut.com/products/zeroview) (note this only works with the Pi Zero or Pi Model A) to attach the camera to the outside of the tank.

[image: ZeroView]

A Pi Zero W and the ZeroView mount would result in a nice single wire setup.

If you prefer a more aquarium theme there is also this [kit](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/octocam-pi-zero-w-project-kit).

[image]

While both of these use a Pi Zero, it would be fairly easy to use with any Pi, given a long enough cable and close enough mounting surface.